# Typescript additional props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a custom input field using typescript and Formik. Could I please get some help on the best way of completing the code below? I need to add in additional props label & name... I have been stuck on this for a while and am hoping that I am missing something very easy here!?

```
{/* {label && <label htmlFor={name} className="text-input-label">{label}</label>} */}
```

Please see the above line in the below code.

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { FieldHookConfig, useField } from "formik";

interface AdditionalProps {
  label: string;
  name: string;
}

const MyTextInput = (props: FieldHookConfig<string>) => {
  const [field, meta] = useField(props);
  return (
    <div className={"text-input " + props.className}>
      {/* {label && <label htmlFor={name} className="text-input-label">{label}</label>} */}
      <div className="card-backdrop">
        <input {...field} placeholder={props.placeholder} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default styled(MyTextInput)``
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: `props: FieldHookConfig<string> & { name: string, label: string } `

Answer (score 2):

Create a new prop as an interface as below and use it in your component as props type

```
interface ComponentProps<T> {
  config : FieldHookConfig<T>;
  label: string;
  name: string;
}
const MyTextInput = (props: ComponentProps<string>) => {}
```

So you can use your formik config(FieldHookConfig) in your component like below
`props.config.className` or `props.config.placeholder` and You can use your additional props like `props.label` and `props.name`

And finally your component looks like

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { FieldHookConfig, useField } from "formik";

interface ComponentProps<T> {
  config : FieldHookConfig<T>;
  label: string;
  name: string;
}

const MyTextInput = (props: ComponentProps<string>) => {
  const [field, meta] = useField(props.config);
  return (
    <div className={"text-input " + props.config.className}>
      {props.label && <label htmlFor={props.name} className="text-input-label">{props.label}</label>}
      <div className="card-backdrop">
        <input {...field} placeholder={props.config.placeholder} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default styled(MyTextInput)
```

Comment: Hi there, - thank you for such a quick response. TS like that, however, I have created an error that I have been seeing along the way....

The way that I am calling the component is as follows:
`<MyTextInput name="displayName" placeholder="Display Name" />`

I am now getting an error:
`Property 'placeholder' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<Pick<ComponentProps<string>, "label" | "name" | "config"> & Partial<Pick<ComponentProps<string>, never>>, "label" | ... 1 more ... | "config"> & { ...; } & { ...; }'. `

Comment: Thanks - but that is how I have called it as per the comment above..?

Comment: placeholder props is in your config so you  call it like                                     <MyTextInput config = { /* put it your fieldhookconfig object */ } name = {"DisplayName"} label = {"Display Name"} ></MyTextInput>

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get the desired outcome by using formiks **Field** & **FieldAttributes** component.

I am able to use all of formiks inbuilt props & useField hook with the ability to pass down additional props to enable complete control over styling.

See below for the code that I have used. :)

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useField, FieldAttributes, Field } from "formik";

type MyTextInputProps = {
  label?: string;
  name: string;
  className?: string;
} & FieldAttributes<{}>;

const MyTextInput: React.SFC<MyTextInputProps> = ({
  label,
  placeholder,
  type,
  className,
  ...props
}) => {
  const [field, meta] = useField<{}>(props);
  return (
    <div className={"text-input " + className}>
      {label && <label className="text-input-label">{label}</label>}
      <div className="card-backdrop">
        <Field placeholder={placeholder} type={type} {...field} />
        {meta.touched && meta.error && (
          <div className="text-input-error">{meta.error}</div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default styled(MyTextInput)
```

this is then called with the following

```
<MyTextInput name="displayName" placeholder="Display Name" />
```